# Determine the maximum period of this potential random number generator, if possible

Tags: probability, general-topology, statistics, discrete-mathematics, random

> Determine the maximum period of the following potential random number
>   generator, if possible.
>
> $x_{n+1} = 65x_n+1 \,\,(\text{ mod } 2048)$

This is an exctract of a big task with more RNG's and I choose this one to see if I do it correct?

I read the article on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length

I would solve it like that:

First of, $1$ and $2048$ need to be relatively prime. They are relatively prime since $\gcd(1,2048)=1$

---

Now we need to make sure that $65-1$ is divisible by all prime factors of $2048$. Prime factors of $2048: 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2$. So this is also good since $64$ is divisible by $2$.

---

Now what is left is that $65-1$ is a multiple of $4$ if $2048$ is a multiple of $4$. This is the case because

$\frac{2048}{4}$ you get an integer and so you also get integer for $\frac{64}{4}$.

All things checked are true so this means that the period of this generator is at most $2048$, so the maximum period is $\approx 2048$?

Comment: Do you want the period of this sequence?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I want the maximum period of the given generator

Comment: If $p$ is a period of this sequence so is $np$ for integer $n$ or I'm wrong?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Sry I don't know that

Comment: Well then! How do we prove that?